# HTML/CSS/JS switch different google calendars is the same frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, calendar

I have multiple Google calendars and I would like to display them on a website within one frame. The commuter call should be changed dynamically. Do let me know if it is possible. I have provided the sample code below.

```
<a href="<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src" class="btn btn-default" >Calendery_1 </a>
<a href="<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src" class="btn btn-default" >Calendery_2 </a>
<a href="<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src" class="btn btn-default" >Calendery_3 </a>
<a href="<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src" class="btn btn-default" >Calendery_4 </a>
```

Comment: Do let me know the what would you like to achieve by using the above code - the purpose of multiple calendars and the reason for using them within a frame so that will try to help you

Comment: I thought "in the same frame". On my website I want to expose the calendar where is the occupancy of each classroom in the school. For greater clarity, I have a separate calendar for each room. Google Calendar offers a link that can be inserted on the page, but it can not switch that by tossing calendars in the same frame.

thanks for the previous correction.

Comment: The requirement is clear and this really helps to provide a solution. Will revert ASAP

Answer (score 0):

The changing of src element can be done in 3 different ways - using plain HTML, using simple JavaScript or using jQuery. It depends on your requirement which one to choose. Below one is a simple HTML response. I have tried below two solutions and it is working fine

**HTML Method**

```
   <p>Click on link bellow to change iframe content:</p>
         <a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=81fmklm3e8fmar82p72jc89ld4%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia/Calcutta" target="search_iframe">TechMocktail</a> -
        <a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=cl5g5tm0fuj0ras7jr5bk29khs%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia/Calcutta" target="search_iframe">TechMocktail Course</a> 

        <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org" style="border: 0" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="search_iframe"></iframe>
```

I have created two Google calendars and tried the above example. Do let me know if this helps or do you need more details.

**JavaScript Method**

```
function go(loc) {
            document.getElementById('calendar').src = loc;
        }

<iframe id="calendar" src="about:blank" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

    <form method="post">
        <input name="calendarSelection" type="button" Value=" Calendar1" onclick="go('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=81fmklm3e8fmar82p72jc89ld4%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia/Calcutta')" />
        <input name="calendarSelection" type="button" value=" Calendar2" onclick="go('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=cl5g5tm0fuj0ras7jr5bk29khs%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia/Calcutta')" />
        <input name="calendarSelection" type="button" value=" Wikipedia"  onclick="go('http://en.wikipedia.org')" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what we needed.